# How can we make appscript webapp compatible with mobile browser

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a webapp created through appscript, and it works perfectly fine on both Desktop and Mobile browsers but when I open it in mobile browser font is quiet small and it is not compatible with difference device.

I have added this, but it is not working i guess :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't try adding these MetaTags to your **doGet** function:

```
.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

**Reference:**

[HtmlOutputMetaTag](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output-meta-tag)

Comment: Thanks for that quick response. it works:)